# How does CMOS battery affect hardware?

Tags: drivers, hardware-failure, cmos

I have seen multiple websites that claim a dead CMOS battery can cause hardware failures due to driver issues. (electronicshub dot org/symptom-of-a-cmos-battery-failure/)

How is this possible if the CMOS is also being powered by the main PSU from the time the computer is powered on? I understand how it could cause the RTC to lose the time if the computer is powered off, but not how it affects the drivers.

Or am I incorrect to assume this, and in reality the motherboard/operating system's vital functions are designed to actually rely on a 3V button battery and not the PSU?

Thank you!

Comment: I think what you are reading is largely misinformation. A dead CMOS battery does not damage a pc.

Comment: That article is nonsense and much of that website is too.

Comment: I've seen computers refuse to boot with a dead CMOS battery, but that was about 15 years ago now. Other than that I've never seen driver failures or anything more than websites refusing to load due to HTTPS or TLS handshaking failing due to the clock being wrong.

Comment: A dead CMOS battery can leak and very terminally damage a PC

Comment: I've had Macs that behave very bizarrely with a [nearly] flat CMOS battery. Anecdotal evidence only, but a new battery immediately fixed it.